# Free Super Personalised Desktop Software

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

Ok, call me a weirdo, but I was wondering if there is some free software out there somewhere which transforms your desktop into more of an actual desktop? Hard to explain, but I would like to stick scalable photos on, rotatble, maybe some notes, videos, links, images. So, it becomes more like an actual desktop rather than just a place of icons, widgets and a wallpaper.

I know, its an odd request, but surely there is something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [BumpTop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BumpTop) wasn't discontinued when they were acquired by the Goog, I would have recommended that. Check out [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/cms/). There is a **huge** theming community for Rainmeter on [Deviantart](http://rainmeter.deviantart.com/).

---

[image]

[Source](http://fiveseven808.deviantart.com/art/Netbook-UX-Rainmeter-theme-158936267)

---

[image]

[Source](http://manj3d.deviantart.com/art/Windows-7-Rainmeter-143123600)

---

Comment: Rainmeter, isn't bad, however it still feels a little tooo structured and technical.

Comment: Bumptop does look like what i was looking for